# Django MultiValueDictKeyError at /accounts/login/

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

so I got a code error MultiValueDictKeyError at /accounts/login/.

[MultiValueDictKeyError picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXqip.png)
The error appears when I'm trying to send password reset email. Here's my code:

**views.py:**

```
from email.policy import default
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

from accounts.forms import registrationForm
from accounts.models import Account
from django.contrib import messages, auth
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

#verification stuff
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = registrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            username= email.split("@")[0]

            user = Account.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, username=username, password=password)
            user.phone_number = phone_number
            user.save()


            #Account activation
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Please activate your account'
            message = render_to_string('accounts/account_verification.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = email
            send_email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            send_email.send()
            return redirect('/accounts/login/?command=verification&email='+email)
    else:
        form = registrationForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }      
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Logged in!')
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid login')
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    messages.success(request, 'Logged out!')
    return redirect('login')

def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
        user = Account._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, Account.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    
    if user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Congratulations! You have joined our site!')
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid activation link')
        return redirect('register')

@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html')

def forgotPassword(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        if Account.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            user = Account.objects.get(email__exact=email)

            # Reset password email
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Reset Your Password'
            message = render_to_string('accounts/reset_password_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = email
            send_email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            send_email.send()

            messages.success(request, 'Password reset email has been sent to your email address.')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Account does not exist!')
            return redirect('forgotPassword')
    return render(request, 'accounts/forgotPassword.html')

def resetpassword_validate(request):
    HttpResponse('ok')
```

**forgotPassword.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<section class="section-conten padding-y" style="min-height:84vh">

        <div class="card mx-auto" style="max-width: 700px; margin-top:100px;">
            <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title mb-4">Reset Password</h4>
          {% include 'includes/alerts.html' %}
          <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="float-right">Got Password? Come on in!</a>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Reset  </button>
              </div>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
         <p class="text-center mt-4">Don't have account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign up</a></p>
         <br><br>  
    </section>

{% endblock %}
```

I've tried setting the **password = request.POST['password']** to **password = request.POST.get('password', '')** but then the code doesn't work correctly and it drops this error message found on views.py **messages.error(request, 'Invalid login')**. [The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewibr.png) it should send an email and display the **messages.success(request, 'Password reset email has been sent to your email address.')**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you provide full error?

Comment: your form sends data to `<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">`  to `login view` but you are trying as you said to send it to `send password reset email`, you need to send your data to apropriate `view`

Comment: also please do not post `views` which don't relate to your problem, such as `register`, `dashboard`, `activate`  etc

Comment: Show your **`accounts/login.html`**

Comment: Your errors related to **login view**, not f̶o̶r̶g̶o̶t̶P̶a̶s̶s̶w̶o̶r̶d̶.